# Inline div causing uneven layout

Tags: css, html, inline

I'm working with Twitter and have pulled a list of all my followers and their screen names down using the API. I'm trying to display them in a nice 'grid' on my web page. However, it currently looks like this:

[image: Bad layout]

The issue happens when the person's screen name is so long that it goes on to two lines. I don't know why it sometimes puts a single person on a line like that...

Here's my CSS code:

```
div.inline { 
float:left; 
padding-left: 40px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 90px;
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<div class = "inline">
    <?php echo $userName; ?><br>
    <?php echo "<img src = ".$userImage." class = ".$class.">"; ?><br>
    <select name = "choice">
        <option value = "blank"></option>
        <option value = "cool">Cool</option>
        <option value = "uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Can anyone help? Perhaps there is a way to put in a blank line after the first line of their name or something if it's less than two lines long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason someone is on a single line is because each div is different heights.  Either wrap the username in an element (div for example) and set a height to that or set a height to the entire inline div.  I think it would be nice to have the images aligned though, so the first option is best.

```
<div class="inline">
    <div class="username"><?=$userName;?></div>
    <?='<img src="'.$userImage.'" class="'.$class.'" alt="'.$userName.'" />';?><br />
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

For 2 lines use the following:

```
.username { 
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 15px;
}
```

Increase height by line-height value for each line you want.

Comment: This fixed both my problems! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="inline">
    <div style="height: 32px; line-height: 16px"><?php echo $userName; ?></div><br />
    <img src=" <?php echo userImage; ?> " class=" <?php echo $class; ?> " /><br />
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The divs height should be equivalent to two lines of text.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unfortunately. The pictures are still out of line.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a fixed height for the name and image. Your problem will be solved.

Update your markup as this:

```
<div class = "inline">
    <div class="name"><?php echo $userName; ?></div>
    <div class="image"><?php echo "<img src = ".$userImage." class = ".$class.">"; ?></div>
    <select name = "choice">
        <option value = "blank"></option>
        <option value = "cool">Cool</option>
        <option value = "uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And CSS to something similar.

```
.name { height: 30px; }
.image { height: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to remove `float:left` and replace with `display:inline-block`, since you really do want `inline` elements (as kind of hinted at with your `class="inline"`).

`inline-block` elements will naturally align to the text baseline, which means that longer names that spill onto new lines will push the vertical position of *all* elements down, therefore the person with the longest name will determine the vertical positioning of the other elements.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ldtv/1/) or example code below:

**CSS**

```
div.inline { 
    display:inline-block; 
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 90px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inline">
    short-ish username<br/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/cats/1"/><br/>
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    name<br/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/cats/2"/><br/>
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    A really, really long username<br/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/cats/3"/><br/>
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    Short again<br/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/cats/4"/><br/>
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="inline">
    V.short<br/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/100/cats/5"/><br/>
    <select name="choice">
        <option value="blank"></option>
        <option value="cool">Cool</option>
        <option value="uncool">Uncool</option>
    </select>
</div>
```